# trackpad gestures

Tags: compiz

Does any one knows a application to detect the multitouch of a laptop and use it to do gestures like macOSX.
Slide sideways with 3 fingers to change virtual desktops
Move upwards with 3 fingers to do a exposé
Move downwards with 3 fingers to show desktop
Configure other gestures that I might need

Answer (score 0):

**Easystroke** is a gesture-recognition application for X11. It aims to be highly configurable while at the same time providing an intuitive user interface. It was designed with a Tablet PC in mind, but it also works well with a mouse.
You can download it from software center.

Comment: thank you for your input is there any other?

Answer (score 0):

I tried gestikk out in the past, but easystroke really had much, much more features and a better user interface. I also looked for an alternative, but I couldn't find any that had at least half amount of easystrokes' features. Anyway.
gesture notifications (ballontip / on-screen-display)
a better gesture recognition algorithm
Install gestikk in Ubuntu Hardy

First you need to download gestikk .deb package from here

wget http://gestikk.reichbier.de/downloads/gestikk_0.6-0ubuntu1_all.deb

Now you have gestikk_0.6-0ubuntu1_all.deb package install .deb package using the following command

sudo dpkg -i gestikk_0.6-0ubuntu1_all.deb

If you get the following error at the time of installation

Selecting previously deselected package gestikk.
(Reading database ... 119493 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking gestikk (from gestikk_0.6-0ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gestikk:
gestikk depends on python-kiwi; however:
Package python-kiwi is not installed.
gestikk depends on python-pyparsing (>= 1.4.7); however:
Package python-pyparsing is not installed.
dpkg: error processing gestikk (--install):
dependency problems -- leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
gestikk

Use the following command to fix

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

This will complete the installation

Using Gestikk

If you want to start gestikk use the following command from your terminal

```
gestikk
```

or

if you want to configuration menu use the following command

```
gestikk -c
```

SOURCE: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/gestikk-mouse-gesture-recognition-in-ubuntu.html